# Complexity of *in* operator in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity

What is the complexity of the `in` operator in Python? Is it theta(n)?

Is it the same as the following?

```
def find(L, x):
   for e in L:
       if e == x:
           return True
   return False
```

`L` is a list.

Comment: It depends on the type of container, since using it with a dictionary or set will be much faster than with an array.

Comment: @BasicWolf I have used L, so it is list

Comment: See the comments thread at the [ActiveState snippet _List with fast membership test (__contains__)_](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577185-list-with-fast-membership-test-__contains__/). Summary: do timing tests.

Comment: @Rastegar `L` doesn't imply a list. `seq` is the most common choice where one wants to imply a list. `L` is a terrible variable name. Single letter ones are bad, and the capital implies it's a class. Even if it was something in particular, Python is dynamic, so state it explicitly in a case like this.

Comment: `L` means `list`? My libtelepathy.so is probably outdated.

Comment: @GarethLatty Using *lst* is also a good name to define a `list`

Comment: For a normal list, your algorithm should be slower - not because it is semantically less efficient, but because Python will the "in" interpret in C as one function, while in yours, every line would be interpreted separately. (Of course, there are probably some optimizations...)

Answer (score 233, accepted):

The complexity of `in` depends entirely on what `L` is. `e in L` will become `L.__contains__(e)`.

See this [time complexity document](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for the complexity of several built-in types.

Here is the summary for `in`:

- list - Average: O(n)
- set/dict - Average: O(1), Worst: O(n)

The O(n) worst case for sets and dicts is very uncommon, but it can happen if `__hash__` is implemented poorly. This only happens if everything in your set has the same hash value.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the complexity of the "in" operator for an OrderedDict?

Comment: After some testing, I can confirm that the complexity of OrderedDict in Python 2.7 appears to be O(1) in the average case.

Comment: @Josh Sherick you don't have to provide tests, all you need are the sources of the [`OrderedDict`](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py), and as you could find out: `OrderedDict` is inherited from `dict`, so the most operations (of course, with exceptions) have **the same complexity**.

Comment: Is the time complexity of "in" operator O(n) for tuple as well?

Comment: What is the time complexity of "in" operator when used with a generator?

Comment: @InheritedGeek yes it is

Comment: @whitehat linear.

Answer (score 23):

It depends entirely on the type of the container. Hashing containers (`dict`, `set`) use the hash and are essentially O(1). Typical sequences (`list`, `tuple`) are implemented as you guess and are O(n). Trees would be average O(log n). And so on. Each of these types would have an appropriate `__contains__` method with its big-O characteristics.

Comment: of value is to include the overhead of generating the hash.

Comment: Hashing data types include `dict` and `set` (as wells as potentially others)

Comment: @Woot4Moo: When you're talking about asymptotic complexity, that isn't relevant. The overhead of generating the hash is constant. When you're dealing with small values of N, profiling becomes important, because, say, 100 >> 2N for small N. But that's a separate issue from what the OP was asking about; for huge N, 100 << 2N, which is what complexity is all about.

Comment: @abarnert well it actually is quite relevant, as you don't arbitrarily choose data structures.  You must consider the use and most common ways the structure will be used, so it actually is important to consider the amount of time for a hash function, especially in a scenario where the has must be computed per iteration of a program.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: If someone is asking about asymptotic complexity, either (a) they expect to deal with a large N, or (b) they're an idiot. I'm assuming the OP is case (a), but either way, the constant factor isn't relevant to the answer.

Comment: I would expect the overhead of hashing to not be quite constant (the number of bytes being hashed would be a factor) but we can probably treat it as such so long as  that doesn't correlate strongly with *n.*

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the container you're testing. It's usually what you'd expect - linear for ordered datastructures, constant for the unordered. Of course, there are both types (ordered or unordered) which might be backed by some variant of a tree.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic `A in B` tests whether `A` is in `B`.

Comment: I'd definitely expect logarithmic time in an ordered structure.

Comment: @dedObed Why would you expect that? Do you expect python to already know whether or not your data are sorted?

Comment: Because if there is a container designed to be ordered, the obvious reason is to allow for logarithmic lookups. But I guess it's just a naming issue, I'd use "linear" where you wrote "ordered" and all would be fine. (In my head -- English as second language here.)

Comment: "Ordered" in Python usually means that the iterator yields elements in the order they were added to the collection. It doesn't usually refer to the case where they are yielded in sorted order (like from a heap), where you'd indeed expect logarithmic time. Maybe this is a case of different terminology between languages, because C++ often seems to use "ordered" in the sense you mean it here.