# 'if not in' time complexity

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity

Could someone explain the time complexity of the following loop?

```
for x in iterable:
    if x not in other_iterable:
        return False
```

I found a really good Python operation time complexity text lecture [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt), and saw that the time for the outer `for` loop was O(N). However, how does the `if x not in other_iterable` part factor into the time complexity? I imagine the loop will be checking `x` against every element in `iterable` until it is found, or the list is exhausted. So what would be the recommended way to make the `if x not in other_iterable` loop take the smallest amount of time possible? Possibly having sorted the `other_iterable`? I'm practically a rookie at understanding time complexity, and would like to know more.

Edit: `other_iterable` would be a list with possible duplicates.

Comment: It depends. What is the data type of `other_iterable`? If it's a list, it's O(N), but if it's a set, it's O(1). (So the whole loop is O(N^2) (well, O(NM)) or O(N), depending)

Comment: @JoranBeasley No it's not, set intersection is still O(N). (Where N is the smaller of the two)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complexity of \*in\* operator in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python)

Comment: A nice ref on collections https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the question you've called them `iterable` so I'm going to assume they're not `set` or similar and that to determine if `x not inother_iterable` is true you have to check the values in `other_iterable` one at a time. For example, this would be the case if they were lists or generators.

Time complexity is about the worst case; it's an **upper** bound. So, in this case the worst case would be in everything in `iterable` was in `other_iterable` but was the last item returned. Then, for each of the `n` items in `iterable` you'd check each of the `m` items in `other_iterable` and the total number of operations would be `O(n*m)`. If `n` is roughly the same size then it's `O(n^2)`.

For example, if `iterable = [8, 8, 8]` and `other_iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` then for each of the 3 items in `iterable` you have to check the 8 items in `other_iterable` until you find out that your `if` statement is false so you'd have `8 * 3` total operations.

The best case scenario would be if the first item in `iterable` was not in `other_iterable`. Then you'd only examine a single element of `iterable` but you'd iterate over all `m` items in `other_iterable` until you learned that the `if` condition was true and you'd be done. That's a total of `m` operations. However, as noted above, big-O time complexity is about worst case scenarios so you wouldn't ordinarily quote this as the complexity.

Comment: Thanks @OliverDain (fellow Wolfpack-er)