# Big O running time of in oprator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm wondering what's the Big O running time of the below simple program:

```
dates = [0,2,3,4]
sample_list = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0, 4):
    sub_list = sample_list[i+1:]
    if dates[i] in sub_list:
        count += 1
```

Is the running time `O(n)` or `O(n**2)`? I know the running time is at lease `O(n)` because I have a for loop, but how about the `if dates[i] in sub_list` statement? What's the running time for that?

Comment: `O(n)` or `O(n**2)` is meaningless without a definition for `n`... What is `n`? the number of elements in `dates`, in `sample_list`, in both? The number of lists?...

Answer (score 3):

Your loop does not seem to depend on the length of your list(s), even though it probably should.  However, the call to `sample_list[i+1:]` will depend on the size of `sample_list` as well as `dates[i] in sub_list`.

For this reason, your code is `O(n)` where `n` is the length is `sample_list`.

Comment: So what if I change it into `for i in range(0, len(dates))` ? Does that give me O(n)?

Comment: As Stefan pointed out, it's already `O(n)`, but it would be better to not hardcode the indices.

Comment: I see. So if I'm understanding it correctly, `if dates[i] in sub_list` doesn't increase the running time to O(n^2). However I was reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python and it seems like an "in" operator in a list has O(n) running time. Since I'm wrapping a for loop outside this in operator. Shouldn't it be O(n^2) for my case?

Comment: It would be `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of `sample_list` and `m` is the length of `dates` if you used `len(dates)` instead of `4` in your for-loop.

Comment: I see what you say. Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @vivi11130704 If you don't have any other questions, feel free to accept my answer :)