# better way to extract item of list A which contain ID from list B?

Tags: python, algorithm

my question is about algorithms for extract data from 2 list of instances which share same ID.
Here is a example:
ClassA has 2 attributes: ID and info, classB has 1 attribute: ID

```
listA         listB
instanceA1    instanceB1
instanceA2    instanceB2
instanceA3
instanceA4
```

what I did is very simple

```
IDs_listB = [l.ID for l in listB]  
out_tab=[] 
for line in listA:
        if line.ID in IDs_listB:
            out_tab.append(line)
```

But this way become very slow and heavy for large data, if `listA` has N lines and M lines for `listB`, O(N*M) the total complexity is too much......

I am thinking of cython or a automate, but is there any way better to so this job?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. In this example, it's not clear what types your variables are.

Comment: You probably want to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: how is `extract` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Counter (O(n+m)) like this

```
from collections import Counter
lst1 = ["1","2","3"]
lst2 = ["1","3","4"]

c = Counter(lst1 + lst2)
print [i for i in c if c[i] > 1]
```

output

```
['1', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set instead of ListB as set uses hashing and faster with `in` keyword as compared to list.

**OR**

Make a dictionary of ListB and use ID as key and `True` as value and search like this.

`for line in listA:
    if dictB.get(line.ID):
       extract(line)`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) you can improve your time complexity to `O(n)` in average case and `O(m*n)` in worst case where the size of lists are **n**, **m** respectively.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,4,6]
s = set(l1)
l3 = [i for i in l2 if i in s]
print(l3) // [2]
```

*Average Time* complexity for lookup in set is `O(1)` where as it reaches to `O(N)` in *Worst Case*. Referenence [Complexity of *in* operator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python).

Comment: thank you, but in my case, my ids are not simple number , they like this : RPS4XP5,AC019181.2,NEUROD1,FRG2FP,RPL9P5.

Comment: @boat  I guess They are strings, So what's the issue you are facing?