# What is big O notation when a not in string in python

Tags: python

i am trying practice some coding question and wondering how I can calculate big O for following code `string[i] in string[i+1:]` and `string[i] not in seens`

```
def findNoCurring(string):
    seens = set()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if not string[i] in string[i+1:] and string[i] not in seens:
            return string[i]
        else:
            seens.add(string[i])
    return None
```

Comment: It's O(n) for strings.  You have to look at every character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The line `string[i] in string[i+1:]` will make your algorithm `O(N^2)`. With this line, you're checking every character in the string with every other character. If `string` = `"abcd"`, you're checking `a` against `b`, `c`, `d`, then `b` against `c`, `d`, and so on. the line `string[i] not in seens` will be O(1) on average since Python sets are implemented something like dictionaries (see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented)).

Note that the `in` operation for Python lists, is, on average, `O(N)`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python)