# Delete dictionary from list dictionaries if the keys don't exist in a list

Tags: python

```
abc = [123,345,678]
var = [{'name':'123, 'age':12},{name:345, 'age':32},{name:789,'age':39}]
```

I want to delete a the dictionary from var if the var['name'] doesn't exist in list abc.

```
final = [{'name':'123, 'age':12},{name:345, 'age':32}]
```

I tried the following

```
for i,element in enumerate(abc):
   if element['name'] in var.keys():
      element['salary'] = '50000'
   else:
       abc.pop(i)
```

it deletes some dicts, but leaves one dict

Comment: How have you tried to solve this? Please show us your attempt and explain how exactly it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list comprehension method:

```
final = [v for v in var if v['name'] in abc]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
final = filter(lambda x: x['name'] in abc, var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend using sets refer [Complexity of *in* operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python)

```
set_abc = set(abc)
final = [x for x in var if x['name'] in set_abc]
```

Comment: You're instantiating a new set for every iteration so it does not help the time complexity at all. You should instantiate the set before using it in the list comprehension.

Comment: @blhsing makes sense. corrected