# Time complexity of in function in python

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I would like to check whether x in list(y), hence I use the code

```
if x in y:
   return True
```

what is the time complexity? is it O(1) or O(n)?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on what exactly `y` is. If `y` is a dictionary or a set then complexity is O(1), if it's a list - then O(n)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of object `y` is.

If `y` is a sequence type like `list` or `tuple`, the time complexity is O(n), because Python has to scan the sequence looking for a match.

If `y` is a hashed type like a `set` or `dict`, the time complexity is typically O(1), because Python can immediately check whether a matching object exists in the hash table.

Update: the question was edited to indicate that `y` is a list. In that case, the time complexity is O(n).

Also see this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python) and more [background info](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).