# This is O(n) time complexity right? if statements dont affect time complexity right?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        storing_list = []
        counter = 0
        for i in nums:
            if i in storing_list:
                counter += 1
            else:
                storing_list.append(i)
        if counter > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This should run in O(n) time right? Leetcode is saying that time limit is exceeded, which means it runs too slow. I am confused on what the run time of this algorithm is.

Comment: Need to know more about `storing_list.append(i)`

Comment: An `if` statement takes the time it takes to evaluate the condition. `i in storing_list` takes the time it takes to find `i`, which depends on the length of `storing_list`

Comment: Hint: use a set, not a list.

Comment: You need to consider the complexity of the individual operations you use. In particular, `in` and `append`. It is more than dubious that they are performed in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other topic [Complexity of *in* operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python), the complexity of `in` of `list` is O(n), so the overall complexity is O(n^2) because you iterate over `nums` and call `in` in the for-loop.

If you want an O(n) solution, you can use `set` instead of `list`, because `in` of `set` has average O(1) complexity. For example,

```py
storing_set = {set}
counter = 0
for i in nums:
    if i in storing_set:
        counter += 1
    else:
        storing_set.add(i)
    if counter > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Sorry. I can't add comments for now so just post an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement takes the time it takes to evaluate the condition.

In this case, the condition is `i in storing_list`, which requires an element-by-element search of `storing_list`. In particular, if `i` is not in the list, the search will take time linear in the nber of elements seen so far, so calling it `n` times on a list of items without duplicates will take quadratic time. Not good.

You would be a lot better off using a set, which can do a lookup in constant time, on average.

Note that counting the number of duplicates and then returning True if the count is greater than one could be a massive waste of time. Suppose the list consists of two identical values followed by 10 million unique values. You could just reurn True as soon as you see the second element, no? The count is never going to go down. Handling the other ten million values is totally pointless.

Comment: Technically, early exit does not change the worst-case complexity.

Comment: @yves: that's obviously true, and I did say "**could be**   a massive waste" for exactly that reason. However, in contexts other than the academic, this sort of inefficiency is going fail code reviews.

Comment: That reminds me of the case of dichotomic search in a sorted array. Many implementations do test for equality of the key on every iteration and perform early exit. Though this is an "obvious" improvement, in fact it slows down the algorithm.

Comment: @yves: that's completely different, although it is an interesting case. But here I'm not suggesting a new test; the test is already being. The difference is what you do when the test fires: increment a count, or break/return. A more similar case is one of my bugbears in code reviews: using `if index(target, prefix) == 0` instead of `if startswith(target, prefix)` (substitute method names appropriate for your language). I got something like a 20% speedup for a single line CL from that one, once. On the service as a whole, not a microbenchmark. These things matter.

Comment: Are you really explaining this to me ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe I'm just counter-trolling. :-)