# Confused about the Time complexity of a nested If statement.(Solved)

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I was trying to figure out what the Big 0 of the code was but got confused on what the Time complexity of a Nested If statement is which checks if a letter is present in an array. If it checks through the entire array then it would be O(n) (worst case) which in turn would make the Big O of the entire code O(n*m) but I was told it is O(n).

What exactly does the If statement does to check the Array?
Code

```
def containscommonitem(arr1,arr2):
  for sym in arr1:
    if sym in arr2:
      print("True")
      break
    else:
      print('False')
      break
containscommonitem(['a','b','c','y'],['m','z','f'])
```

Comment: "I was told" by whom? Is `arr2` [something with *O(1)* inclusion tests](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)? It isn't in your example.

Comment: Both branches of the `if` statement have a `break`, therefore the loop will stop after the first iteration.  Did you intend this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complexity of \*in\* operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python)

Comment: To be precise: What you have is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). An [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is something different.

Comment: Teacher in college and arr1 and arr2 are Lists @tadman

Comment: Yeah sorry for the mistake it is indeed a List @Matthias

Comment: Yes I only wanted to check If there's a common element in the Lists. Without the "break" the code iterates through the whole arr1 even if a common element is found.@JohnGordon

Comment: @MrNobody You say "**the** `break`", but there are two of them, right? Are you sure there should be two?

Comment: With both `break` statements this is `O(len(arr2))`, because it only tests the first element of `list1`. But then the name of the function is misleading.

Comment: Yeah trincot pointed that mistake out. Where I made the mistake was that I only verified to code using only two inputs. @slothrop

Answer (score 3):

If we're being precise, since we have two different varying inputs we can't just describe the complexity in terms of one of them only unless we justify it.

So say N refers to the size of arr1 and M refers to the size of arr2.
Then in the worst case you'd have O(N*M). You should consider why this is different from O(N^2) in real life scenarios.

Also as John Gordon points out the break statement drastically changes the way this is analyzed as well, because then you might care about the average case a lot more rather than the worst case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out O(n*m). So the code does have a n^2 complexity if we consider both of same arr1 and arr2 of same size? @pitabread

Comment: Of course. If n==m then n*m==n^2.

Comment: @MrNobody But we normally consider the complexity of an algorithm in its general case. So unless n==m is a requirement of the function, it would be wrong to describe that as the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: So if I used a Set to store the values of arr1 while using a for loop and then use a If statement to check if items for arr2 exist in the Set then it would be O(n)? @Barmar

Comment: @MrNobody You need to use a set for `arr2`. "value in set" is O(1), but iterating over a set is O(n).

Comment: @MrNobody what I was getting at is if you have expectations about the sizes of N and M (either through statistics or some other *a priori* knowledge), then O(N*M) could imply significantly different things (linear vs. polynomial). Which is why it would be very wrong to say it's O(N^2).

Comment: `def containscommonitem(arr1,arr2):
  myset=set()
  for sym in arr1:
    if sym not in myset:
      myset.add(sym)

  for sym in arr2:
    return any(sym in myset for sym in arr2)

print(containscommonitem(['a','b','c','y'],['m','z','v']))` Does this work @Barmar?

Comment: `def containscommonitem(arr1, arr2): myset = set(arr1); return any(i in myset for i in arr2)` @MrNobody You don't need 2 loops over `arr2`.

Comment: So is O(n^2) worse than O(n*m)? @pitabread

Comment: So what is the complexity of `def containscommonitem(arr1, arr2): myset = set(arr1); return any(i in myset for i in arr2)` ? Is it O(n)? @Barmar

Comment: Yes, it's O(n), where n = len(arr2)

Comment: Actually O(m + n). Creating the set is O(len(arr1)), checking for intersection is O(len(arr2))

Comment: You should think of it line by line and function by function and then tally up. Never guess.

Potential breakdown to check cost
a) set(arr1)
b) i in myset
c) for i in arr2
d) any()

and then figure out whether those need to be added or multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop only makes one iteration, because its body is guaranteed to execute a `break`. That means every statement you have there is executed at the most once. The only one among those statements that is not O(1) is `if sym in arr2`. The `in` operator might have to scan `arr2` completely, so the worst case time complexity is O(m) where m is the size of `arr2`. The size of `arr1` is not relevant because only its first entry is inspected.

Now, the name of your function suggests that it should output "False" when the two lists have no common value. But then it is wrong: you cannot know that if you have only looked at the first value in `arr1`. For instance, your code will output "False" for this input:

```
containscommonitem(['a','m'],['m'])
```

...because it never looked at the "m" in the first list.

The correction would be to move that print of `False` in an `else` clause of the `for` statement:

```
def containscommonitem(arr1,arr2):
    for sym in arr1:
        if sym in arr2:
            print("True")
            break
    else: # when the for loop has finished without executing a break
        print('False')
```

Now the worst case time complexity is O(n*m). Needless to say there are more efficient ways to do this -- by using `set`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. So if I remove 'break' and let the code run it would be O(n*m)?

Comment: Yes that's right